# Collect user information when click on download link

Tags: plugins

We have several links to downloadable content (i.e. pdfs), but we want to collect some user information before the user can download. We found a plugin called Opt-In Panda that would hide content and display it after the user enters their information, but the problem is that the links are spread out on the page and the user would have to re-enter their information for each link they click and we want them to be able to download all the links after filling in their information the first time.

How could I use this so that it only collects information one time and then lets the user download from all the links?

Comment: Thank you for your post, try asking in the plugin forum please.

Comment: Please show us what you already tried in code. Thanks.